# How to delete data from mongoose collection by onclick?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, fetch

I am new to mongodb, and I have created a todo list app using mongodb as a database. When user types something it saves to the mongoose collection, But when I try to delete the data from mongoose collection by onclick, It goes in order like If I click on the second button it will delete me the first data then second data and then third, It doesn't matter which button i am clicking It always goes in order(1,2,3,etc...)

Here is my code

app.js

```
router.delete('/Delete_Data',  (request, response) => {
    item.findOneAndDelete({}, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return response.status(500).send();
        }
        else{
            return response.json({data});
        }
    });
    
});
```

script.js

```
async function deleteLSItem(){
  
  let options = {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  const response = await fetch('/Delete_Data' , options);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

`deleteLSItem()` is a delete button

```
<td class="table-buttons" id="margin-padding"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary delete-btn" onclick="deleteLSItem()"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><span>Delete</span></td>
```

[image: Here is the output]

Answer (score 1):

```
router.delete('/Delete_Data',  (request, response) => {
item.findOneAndDelete({'_id':9898}, (err, data) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return response.status(500).send();
    }
    else{
        return response.json({data});
    }
});
```

});

By specifying fliter in  `item.findOneAndDelete({}...` by '{}' You 're deleting the first item in the collection. Let's say id of the item that you want to delete is 9898. Then your code should look like above

see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/index.html

Comment: Could you please give me an example with my code

Comment: `db.scores.findOneAndDelete(
   { "_id" : "id of the item that you want to delete" }
)`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to delete dynamic values.

Comment: you want to delete item that you select. right?

Comment: yes, i want to delete item that i click on it

Comment: Yeah, exactly, You have to pass id of the item that you select in to the curly braces. give it a whirl

Comment: Could you please give an example, if you have time